# How to convert a number in the following format 20160715 into Date format like 15/07/2015

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, reporting-services

In access database i have the query in thre following format

```
IIf([x]=0,0,(Mid(Trim(Str([x])),5,2) & "/" & Mid(Trim(Str([x])),7,2) & "/" & Left(Trim(Str([x])),4)))
```

What would be the query in sql server?

Answer (score 2):

I would convert it from a string to a date time, and then back to the format you need it to be such as:

```
convert(varchar,convert(datetime,yourvariable,112),103)
```

Formats : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms187928.aspx